# Azure OCR API stalls after 90 images. How to fix connection error?

Tags: python, azure, loops, connection, ocr

I'm trying to run the Azure OCR API on 6000+ images. Unfortunately the code stalls after just 90 images.

**Documentation:**

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/python-print-text#prerequisites
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts/python-disk

**Input:** 6000+ Images (.png)

**Desired Output:**

1. File with extracted text only
2. File with extracted text and their corresponding bounding boxes

**Error Msg:** ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /vision/v2.0/ocr?language=unk&detectOrientation=true (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))

I've provided a delay of 60 seconds after every 10 images, which should ideally take care of the 20 transactions per minute quota.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

import glob
import os
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time

# Replace the value of subscription_key with your subscription key.
subscription_key = "{key}"
assert subscription_key

# Replace the value of vision_base_url (not necessary for trial version)
vision_base_url="https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v2.0/"
analyze_url = vision_base_url + "ocr"

# Initializing Source and Output Directories
source_directory = glob.glob('folder/with/6000/images/*.png')
output_directory_textFiles = 'folder/for/saving/6000/textFiles/'
output_directory_JSONFiles = 'folder/for/saving/6000/JSONFiles/'

if not os.path.exists(output_directory_textFiles):
        os.makedirs(output_directory_textFiles)

if not os.path.exists(output_directory_JSONFiles):
        os.makedirs(output_directory_JSONFiles)

# Define Function for Extracting Text

def extract_text(image_path):
# Read the image into a byte array
image_data = open(image_path, "rb").read()
headers    = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key,'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'}
params     = {'language': 'unk', 'detectOrientation': 'true'}
response = requests.post(analyze_url, headers=headers, params=params, data=image_data)
analysis = response.json()

# Extract the word bounding boxes and text.
line_infos = [region["lines"] for region in analysis["regions"]]
word_infos = []
for line in line_infos:
    for word_metadata in line:
        for word_info in word_metadata["words"]:
            word_infos.append(word_info)
return(word_infos)

# Generating Text and JSON Files

counter = 0
for image in sorted(source_directory):
    counter += 1
    print(r'Processing %d %s' %(counter, image))

    word_infos = extract_text(image)

    filename = image.split('/')[-1].replace('.png', '')

    if len(word_infos) != 0:
        bboxOutput = pd.DataFrame(word_infos)
        bboxOutput[['x','y', 'width','height']] =     bboxOutput['boundingBox'].str.split(',',expand=True)
        bboxOutput = bboxOutput.drop(['boundingBox'], axis=1)

        textFile = bboxOutput['text']     

        textFile = textFile.to_csv(r'{}/{}.txt'.format(output_directory_textFiles, filename), header = False, index = None, sep = ',')
        jsonFile = bboxOutput.to_json(orient = 'records')
        with open(r'{}/{}.txt'.format(output_directory_JSONFiles, filename), 'w') as f:
            f.write(jsonFile)
            f.close()

    else:
        word_infos = pd.DataFrame(word_infos)
        textFile = word_infos.to_csv(r'{}/{}.txt'.format(output_directory_textFiles, filename), header = False, index = None, sep = ',')
        jsonFile = word_infos.to_json(orient = 'records')
        with open(r'{}/{}.txt'.format(output_directory_JSONFiles, filename), 'w') as f:
            f.write(jsonFile)
            f.close()

    if (counter % 10) == 0:
        time.sleep(60)

    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try to change your `time.sleep` call to `3` or `4` seconds after each image instead of `60` seconds after 10 images.

Although the limit for the free tier is 20 per minute, the paid has a limit of 10 per second, so it's possible your are hitting a limit that messes-up the throttling mechanism (your code might be sending the 10 images in less than a second).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Tried with different delay values (4s-10s). Resulted in the same error!

Comment: pretty sure the code isn't sending more than 10 images under 1 second.